# Wordpress wp_list_pages() permalink

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I've added a wp_dropdown_pages() dropdown on my theme and I'm having an irritating issue with it - basically it ignores my pretty permalink structure and tries to access the page via the supplied ID.

Does anyone know how to tie it into the pretty permalink structure?
Code for dropdown is as follows:

```
wp_dropdown_pages( 'child_of=21&hierarchical=true&depth=3&name=pageselect&selected='.$post->ID );
```

I've noticed the solution likely uses the get_permalink function but I'm unsure as to where it should be placed!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have review it and find no solution of this function but if you want to change the function with  this 
`https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages`
then your problem will be solved so it's my advice please use it.

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: I was worrying that may be the case, but I've been assured it's do-able. Is anyone aware of how I'd implement the permalink? I don't mind over-riding the defaults or hackfixing just to get this sorted!